# Dividing a polygon into a given number of equal areas

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

I'm using a [Style](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_Style.html) with [Stroke](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_Stroke.html) and [Fill](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_Fill.html) to have something like this for [Polygon](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_Polygon.html):

```
const feature = new Feature(
        new Polygon([
             xPos.map((x, index) => {
                  return transform([parseFloat(x), parseFloat(yPos[index])], 'EPSG:3857', projection);
             })
        ])
    );

feature.setStyle(
      new Style({
           stroke: new Stroke({
           color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
      }),
      fill: new Fill({color: `#${feature.getProperties().bgColor}`})
    })
 );
```

[image]

Now, I'd like to divide polygon into a given number of equal areas (with different colors). Something like this:

[image]

What should I do to achieve this?

Many thanks.

Comment: There are many non-unique divisions.

Comment: @zabop: I don't get your point. I just want to divide polygon into a given number of equal areas. There is no any strict rule about the shape that we need to divide into.